# Error when try to define a new module in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to load a module in my Rails application but I'm getting the following error:

> Expected /Users/ha/Projects/MyProject/app/services/user.rb to define User

I have this folder structure

```
/app
   /controllers
      users_controller.rb
   /models
      ...
   /services
      web_services.rb
      user.rb
```

**web_services.rb:**

```
module WebServices

  include HTTParty

  def test
     Rails.logger.debug 'webservices works!!!'
  end
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
module WebServices
  class User
     def test_user
        Rails.logger.debug 'user works'
     end
  end
end
```

**I get the error when I try to instantiate the user in the user_controller.rb:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include WebServices

  def index
    user = WebServices::User.new
    user.test_user
  end

end
```

**I've tried to add the following code in the application.rb but not worked**

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/services)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/**/"]
```

**And I've tried the following code but not worked too (environment.rb):**

```
Dir['../app/services/*'].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

**Rails 3.2.11** and **Ruby 1.9.3p194**

Does anybody help me?

Comment: this won't solve your problem, however Rails 3.2.11 is vulnerable to a remote code execution vulnerability. You should upgrade to 3.2.12 ASAP. More information: http://bit.ly/UdLiVr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message cleary says, that the loader **was able** to find and have tried to load `user.rb`. Hence playing with `config.autoload_paths` won’t resolve an issue.

This error usually occurs when someone defined a model that accidentally maps to an existing filename. Try to rename `User` to smth very different:

```
~ cat …/myuser.rb
class MyUser
  def test_user
    Rails.logger.debug 'user works'
  end
end
```

This should make it working.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Rails tries to find a file with the declaration of your classes using the module name (when given) and the class name to introspect the path to the file. When you do:

```
WebServices::User.new
```

Rails will try to find a directory `web_services` because of the module name, and a file `user.rb` inside it. A "fast" way to solve this issue is to create the following dir structure in your project:

```
app/
  services/
    web_services/user.rb
    web_services.rb
```

Note that you don't need to specify the `services` dir in your `autoload` configuration, because any dir inside `app` already is in the Rails load path.

Comment: Hey Valeriano, how are you dude? I had already chosen another answer but I'll test your solution because, for me, your answer make more sense. +1 for you. Tks for helping! See ya!

Comment: Nice @danilodeveloper, let me know if it works for you! You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[
  "#{config.root}/app/services",
  "#{config.root}/app/services/**/"
]
```

Comment: In Rails 3 (I don't exactly in what version it started) any directory inside app/ is automatically included in rails's load path.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in the past somewhere,

in user_services.rb(Note: file name structure is importent in rails)

```
module UserServices
  class User
    def test_user
      Rails.logger.debug 'user works'
    end
  end
end
```

two ways you can solve this issue.

use 
`include UserServices` in `WebServices`
OR

`Webservices.include UserServices` at the end of user_services.rb